# How to use the u-net network model, my network model always reports errors

Tags: python

I want to segmented the Endovis-2018 dataset using the u-net model, but I always get an error"[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_12010]"

I tried to modify and create a list of tags, but to no avail.

Comment: # 图片位置
input_dir = 'train/new_picture/'
# 标注信息位置
target_dir = 'train/label_gray/'
img_size =  (160,160)
batch_size = 32
# 图像路径
input_img_paths = sorted([os.path.join(input_dir, fname)
                          for fname in os.listdir(input_dir)
                          if fname.endswith('.png')])
# 目标值路径
target_img_paths = sorted([os.path.join(target_dir, fname)
                           for fname in os.listdir(target_dir)
                           if fname.endswith('.png')and not fname.startswith(".")])

Comment: background_tissue = [0]
instrument_shaft = [150]
instrument_clasper = [179]
instrument_wrist = [188]
kidney_parenchyma = [89]
covered_kidney = [54]
thread = [29]
clamps = [164]
suturing_needle = [240]
suction_instrument = [66]
small_intestine = [109]
ultrasound_probe = [169]
edge = [255]

Comment: # 模型编译
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")                        # 模型训练，epoch设为5
epochs = 15
model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_gen)